# DataBinding in library project

Tags: android, android-library, android-databinding

If I define a layout in a library project and enable data binding in the library project, it still does not work. Is this normal? Should it be possible to define layouts in a library project and use them with data binding in another project?

Is there more I need to do than following:

- enable data binding in the library project and the main project. Like following:

  ```
  android {
      dataBinding.enabled = setup.enableDataBinding
  }
  ```
- include the layout from the library project the same way as I would do it with a layout from the main project

I do following:

```
 <include
    android:id="@+id/viewTestMainProject"
    layout="@layout/view_main_project"/>

<include
    android:id="@+id/viewTestLibrary"
    layout="@layout/view_from_library" />
```

The first include is created as `ViewMainProjectBinding` and the second as `View` in my binding... (Both layouts are wrapping their content with `layout` tags of course).

**EDIT**

It seems like the problem is only in the IDE, it's is marking the included layouts as `View` altough they are actually the corresponding `...Binding` class... Clean build + invalidate cache + restart IDE does not solve the problem.

Any ideas what could help?

Comment: Facing the same issue, did you find a fix?

Comment: No. But everything is working even with this IDE bug...

Comment: Any fixes since then?